# Run python code on OpenShift

Tags: python, openshift

I'm feel soo noobie asking this question. But is there any documentation of how to run a python code on PoenShift?

Im waitin your answer thankss!!

Comment: https://docs.openshift.com/online/using_images/s2i_images/python.html

Comment: Would also suggest reading https://www.openshift.com/promotions/deploying-to-openshift.html if new to OpenShift. The core build/deployment examples in that uses Python, although the sample application may be a bit confusing as it is a general purpose app designed to demonstrate lots of things. Also work though examples at https://learn.openshift.com/introduction/ which also use some Python sample apps.